# Accessing functions of a derived crtp class from the base calls

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I need to be able to access a static method of the derived class, from within a base CRTP class. Is there a way in which I can achieve this?

Here is example code:

```cpp
#define REQUIRES(...) std::enable_if_t<(__VA_ARGS__), bool> = true
template<typename Derived>
struct ExpressionBase {
    Derived& derived() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
    const Derived& derived() const { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this); }

    constexpr static int size()
    {
        return Derived::size();
    }

    template<typename T, REQUIRES(size() == 1)>
    operator T() const;
};

struct Derived : public ExpressionBase<Derived>
{
    constexpr static int size()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: That looks like it could work, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including a text copy of the error message that you don't understand how to solve.

Comment: That could is perfectly working, cannot reproduce (whatever you error might be...)

Comment: I updated it with the derived class. The error message is `incomplete type not allowed`.

Comment: Your code does not compile because the header for enable_if is missing. Please always post a full, complete example that reproduces the issue. Additionally, the code seems to work: https://wandbox.org/permlink/wsUB8HxWihbC70fD.

Comment: @Jens I believe that the REQUIRES part is key to getting the error. I do have <type_traits> included. I believe the issue is that the compiler tries to initialize the base size() function before the derived one, because it is in the REQUIRES statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deriving from `ExpressionBase<Derived>` involves the instantiation of `ExpressionBase<Derived>`, therefore involves the declaration of the entity

```cpp
template<typename T, REQUIRES(size() == 1)>
operator T() const;
```

Here, `std::enable_if_t` got a template argument that is ill-formed (because `Derived` isn't complete yet). The [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) rule does not apply here, because the ill-formed expression is not in direct context of template argument type, thus it is treated as a hard error.

In order to make the ill-formation happen at an immediate context, use the following code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <bool B, class T>
struct lazy_enable_if_c {
    typedef typename T::type type;
};

template <class T>
struct lazy_enable_if_c<false, T> {};

template <class Cond, class T> 
struct lazy_enable_if : public lazy_enable_if_c<Cond::value, T> {};

template <class T>
struct type_wrapper {
    using type = T;
};

#define REQUIRES(...) std::enable_if_t<(__VA_ARGS__), bool> = true
template<typename Derived>
struct ExpressionBase {
    Derived& derived() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
    const Derived& derived() const { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this); }

    struct MyCond {
        static constexpr bool value = Derived::size() == 1;
    };

    template<typename T, typename = typename lazy_enable_if<MyCond, type_wrapper<T>>::type>
    operator T () const {
        return T{};
    }
};

struct Derived : public ExpressionBase<Derived>
{
    constexpr static int size() {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    int i = d;
    return 0;
}
```

It is actually adapted from `boost`, which you can find more details [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html#sec:enable_if_lazy).

Comment: What's the purpose of the size non-type template argument here? Because if I use a template like this, then all of the other details are unnecessary I believe, since I can just use enable_if_t on the non-type size argument.

Comment: @lightxbulb It has...absolutely no use! Added during testing, forgot to delete :) Have edited the answer.

Comment: Much appreciated. I'll try it on the morrow.

Comment: Isn't the `typename = ...` an issue. I am specifically referring to:

"A common mistake is to declare two function templates that differ only in their default template arguments. This does not work because the declarations are treated as redeclarations of the same function template (default template arguments are not accounted for in function template equivalence)."

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

This is the main reason why I am using: `std::enable_if_t<(__VA_ARGS__), bool> = true`.

Comment: After more experiments, it turns out this works not because of the lazy evaluation, but rather because you coupled the condition with `T`. So this does not get instantiated until the cast is called. For instance this works: `template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<(Derived::size() == 1), T> >`, but the problem is the one pointed out in my previous comment.

Comment: @lightxbulb (1) Using `typename = ...` is not an issue if you don't declare two function templates that differ only in their default template arguments. (2) Using `typename = ...` alone does not resolve the issue, you have to use `lazy_enable_if` too. (Although it compiles in MSVC, it does not compile in both gcc and clang)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I used the `enable_if_t<...,true> = bool`, so I can have multiple overloads. I wasn't aware about the fact that this works only on msvc (intellisense actually thinks it is wrong). Thank you for clarifying this. Is there a way I can extend this to work with multiple overloads?

Comment: @lightxbulb Give it dummy template parameters to differ the deifinitions: [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q0BQ3EPj58ZhYEmU)

Comment: I am trying to avoid such things. Will concepts and constraints solve this issue?